# i've a local variable unused in a function that made a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, local-variables

I've a local variable that's not used in a function. This function does a matrix and returns that matrix empty.

I've tried to use 'i' variable using an "if i is None: pass" but the issue continue.

```
def create_matrix(rows, columns):
    matrix = [[None] * columns for i in range(rows)]
    return matrix
```

i want to dismiss this issue. Is there any way to do it? I know it's a stupid problem but i'm a little bit obsessed with have my code fully clean.

Comment: What issue? I don't see any unused variable. This code works for me.

Comment: yeah but the 'i' variable isn't be used anywhere. That's the issue that i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no issue if you never use an iterator variable. `i` in your code behaves like an iterator in a `for` that is not used:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  // do something without using i
```

This would be ok in any language like C, C++, PHP...

However, if you really don't want named variables that are not used in any expression, you call it `_`:

```
def create_matrix(rows, columns):
    matrix = [[None] * columns for _ in range(rows)]
    return matrix
```

The `_` variable is a implicit variable. It always exists, so you are not declaring anything new. It always has the value of the last evaluated expression and may be used in `for`s like that.